# fullpage.js page structure breaks and becomes unusable upon screen resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js on a page of a site i'm building. Everything is working as intended and i've been very happy with the experience thus far. I've ran into one small issue which i can't seem to resolve.

I've set the responsiveWidth: 961 so when the screen size is below 961px, the slider feature is disabled. Now when trying to resize the screen (up and down) on the FIRST slide (labelled: properties) past the above mentioned breakpoint, everything is fine.

However when trying to resize the screen when the viewport is on the second (and above) slides, the html structure completely breaks below width 961px.

Please visit: http://viv-homes.dafox.uk/properties/ to replicate the issue.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [an open issue about it](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/2426) in the fullpage.js' github issues tacker

As you can see, it is marked as "Fixed on dev". Which means the problem has been solved in [the developing branch](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/tree/dev) and will get merged for the next release v 2.9.0.

If you want to get rid of the issue feel free to use [the developing version](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/blob/dev/jquery.fullPage.js).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. v 2.9.0 has partially fixed the issue. The page structure no longer breaks when scaling the size down however, i have a filter above the image on slide 3 and when scaling the size down below 961px, the filter is being automatically applied to all the slides.

Comment: Probably your own code creating the filter and nothing to do with fullPage.js. The fullPage.js was solved on the dev branch as I said.

Comment: My apologies, it was something to do with my code indeed. Thank you for all your help. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You must assume that a user won't be opening your site on a developer's mode, thus every time you change the screen size, reload the page. Given that users who open the site will be using a fixed screen size. It's not the issue of it breaking down, but in my opinion, js won't read the code the second time once it already loaded, wherein it already read the part of greater than 961px and when you go to lesser than 961px, the code for lesser than 961px will be the last info it will leave for your site. I hope it helped.